# How can I mask the visibility of the text with the overlapping element using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you see the GIF provided below the text only appears after it has crossed the Black Dot. Until then it is invisible. This was made using Flash but how can we achieve this using CSS?

[image: Logo GIF]

Here is what I've got so far:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Mono");
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #222;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Ubuntu Mono";
}

.ypn-logo {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 220px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ypn-text {
  font-size: 3.5em;
  color: white;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
  margin-left: -80px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.ypn-text:before {
  background: red;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 180px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
}

.ypn-logo:hover>.ypn-text:before {
  left: 50px;
}

.ypn-text:after {
  background: #222;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 180px;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
  top: 95px;
  left: 130px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ypn-logo:hover>.ypn-text:after {
  left: 60px;
}

.ypn-logo:hover>.ypn-text {
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ypn-logo">
  <div class="ypn-text">RUN</div>
</div>
```

I thought of making a div and locking its right border with the central axis of the dot in the middle but this hides the Green and Red elements also. Is there a way to just block the text element but not other elements?

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Mono");
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #222;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Ubuntu Mono";
}

.ypn-logo {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 220px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ypn-text {
  font-size: 3.5em;
  color: white;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
  margin-left: -80px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.ypn-before {
  background: red;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 180px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
}

.ypn-logo:hover>.ypn-before {
  left: 50px;
}

.ypn-after {
  background: #222;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 180px;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
  top: 95px;
  left: 130px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.ypn-logo:hover>.ypn-after {
  left: 60px;
}

.ypn-logo:hover>.ypn-text {
  margin-left: 80px;
}

.ypn-after:after {
  width: 130px;
  background: black;
  height: 3em;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ypn-logo">
  <div class="ypn-before"></div>
  <div class="ypn-text">YPN</div>
  <div class="ypn-after"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the text the child of an element with a background color. Then make the mask by creating an element with a dot and a div set to the background color of the parent. Make the parent's `overflow:hidden` so the colored area isn't seen as it moves to uncover the text.

```js
$('.overlay').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hidden');
});

$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.overlay').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  background: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}

.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  transition: left 2s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: calc( -100% + 60px);
}

.overlay.hidden {
  left: 0;
}

.overlay::after {
  content: '';
  background: black;
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.text {
  font-size: 50px;
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">ezoom</div>
  <div class="overlay hidden"></div>
</div>

<p> click the circle to toggle the animation</p>
```

---

**EDIT :**
After using the above principle, here's the final code for the effect you need:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu+Mono");
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #222;
  font-family: "Ubuntu Mono";
}

.ypn-logo {
  background: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 220px;
}

.ypn-before {
  background: red;
  content: '';
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 180px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 180px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}

.ypn-text {
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 3.2em;
  color: #ddd;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}

.ypn-dot {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  left: -35px;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}

.ypn-dot:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #222;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  top: 70px;
  right: -25px;
  transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
}

.ypn-logo:hover>.ypn-before {
  left: 20px;
}

.ypn-logo:hover>.ypn-before .ypn-dot {
  left: -135px;
}

.ypn-logo:hover>.ypn-before .ypn-text {
  left: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ypn-logo">
  <div class="ypn-before">
    <div class="ypn-text">RUN</div>
    <div class="ypn-dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea where you can rely on one element and consider a width/margin animation:

```css
.box {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1em;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  border-radius:1em 0 0 1em;
  
  background: radial-gradient(#000 0.48em, transparent 0.5em) left/1em 1em no-repeat;
  
  width:0;
  margin-left:200px;
  padding: 5px 1em 5px 0;
  transition:1s;
}

body:hover .box {
  width:200px;
  margin-left:0px;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  some text
</div>
```

To avoid setting a specific width you can adjust alignment and consider `max-width`:

```css
.container {
  text-align:right;
  width:500px;
}

.box {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1em;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  overflow:hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
  border-radius:1em 0 0 1em;
  
  background: radial-gradient(#000 0.48em, transparent 0.5em) left/1em 1em no-repeat;
  
  max-width:0;
  padding: 5px 1em 5px 0;
  transition:max-width 1s,padding 0s 1s;
}

body:hover .box {
  max-width:100%;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 1em;
  transition:max-width 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="box">
  some text
</div>
</div>
```